# All php file result in 404 on nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, system-administration

I'm installing Wordpress in my server with nginx.
The configuration that I hope to obtain is:
ON www.mydomain.com I WANT the index contained in /webapps/sitoweb/
ON www.mydomain.com/wordpress/ I WANT my wordpress

I've put wordpress in the folder /var/www/ and I've configured nginx as you can see (I haven't reported the portion of the code in which I declare the rewrite rules for the ssl):

```
server{

    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    listen 443;
    ssl on;

    location / {

       alias /webapps/sitoweb/;
       if ($request_uri ~* ".html") { rewrite ^(/.+)\.html$ $scheme://$host$1 permanent;}
       rewrite ^(/.+)\/$ $scheme://$host$1  permanent;
       try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
       error_page 404 = /404.html;

       location ~* \.html$ {
           expires -1;
       }

       location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
           expires 168h;
           add_header Pragma public;
           add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
       }

       location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
       }

     }

       location /wordpress/ {

            alias /var/www/;
            autoindex off;

            location ~ \.php$ {

                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
            }

    }
```

Now if I go:

- On www.mydomain.com/index.html I obtain the index contained in /webapps/sitoweb/ [OK!]
- On www.mydomain.com/wordpress/readme.html I can see the file contained in /var/www/readme.html [OK!!]
- On www.mydomain.com/wordpress/index.php the file index.php is not found!!!! [ERROR]

I underline that the file index.php is correctly locate in the directory /var/www/!!!

I also put a file info.php in /webapps/sitoweb/ and I can see it in www.mydomain.com/info.php!!!

**Ergo php files under /webapps/sitoweb/ is correctly displayed but php files in /var/www/ is not found!!**

Comment: optimize your locations logically. Try `location ~ ^\/wordpress\/.+\.php$`there inside of `location /wordpress/`

Comment: Still not working...